# Jasper Report: Title should completely take first page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a report using jasper. The requirement is to create title, pageHeader, columnHeader, details and summary. Along with that the first page should contain only title and remaining other things should start from page 2 onwards.

I am unable to get a property which sets title to take completely first page.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

for other bands like columnHeader, details, summary , pageHeader put  print when expression new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} != 1)